# Uploading image from URL without saving them

Tags: python, http, python-requests, base64

I tried to download an image from an url using this.

```py
x = requests.get(url).content
```

This saves the image, but saves it as bytes. I wanted to know how i could download the image as a jpeg and upload it in another request without downloading them to my url.

I tried using the urllib.retrieve function but it downloaded the files.

Comment: Uploading is a POST method, so try using `requests.post()`

Comment: I'm trying to download an image and then post.

Comment: You don't have to download it, you can send the bytes directly using `requests.pos()`

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you want to transfer an image from one site to another without downloading it.

There are two excellent `requests` features to do it - [iteration over response content](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow) and [uploading data in chunks](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#chunk-encoded-requests).

So you can do it in two steps:

1. Perform `GET` request for the image. Postpone its content processing until step 2.
2. Upload image content to target server using `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` [HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding). Use `iter_content()` generator to split image content by chunks.

Example:

```py
import requests

# get image without downloading its content
example_jpg_url = "https://2krota.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/fd2880eb2e0275bae3298bd231bd78de.jpg"
download_request = requests.get(example_jpg_url, stream=True)  # no data downloaded yet

# upload image to destination in chunks
destination_url = "http://localhost:8888"
upload_request = requests.post(destination_url, data=download_request.iter_content(8192))
print(upload_request.status_code, upload_request.request.headers)
```